# Cordova 5.0 Back Button Exits jQuery Mobile App

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-2015, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm building a Cordova 5.0.0 application with Visual Studio 2015 RC and jQuery Mobile ([multipage app](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/pages-multi-page/)) (jQuery 2.1.4, jQuery Mobile 1.4.5), and I'm experiencing behavior with the back-button contrary to my understanding of how it should work.  Right now, all my testing and development is being done on/for Windows Phone 8.1.  The only plugins I'm using are [cordova-plugin-media](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media), which has a dependency on [cordova-plugin-file](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file), though I'm not explicitly using the file plugin.

**The problem**

No matter what page I'm on, if I press the hardware back button, the app just goes to background (doesn't close, just the app is navigated away from).  From everything that I've read, I understand that the back button is supposed to work like page navigation by default.  (That is, if you go from page1 to page2 and press back, then you go to page1).

So, I've tried overriding the back-button with my own implementation, but I can't get the [backbutton event](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#backbutton) to fire.

Here is some code:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    document.addEventListener( 'deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind( this ), false );

    function onDeviceReady() {
        console.log("deviceReady");
        // Handle the Cordova pause and resume events
        document.addEventListener( 'pause', onPause.bind( this ), false );
        document.addEventListener( 'resume', onResume.bind( this ), false );

        // TODO: Cordova has been loaded. Perform any initialization that requires Cordova here.
        console.log('assign back button');
        document.addEventListener('backbutton', function (e) {
            console.log("backbutton");
            window.history.back();
            return false;
        }, false);
    };
```

When I run my app, `deviceReady` makes it to the console, and so does `assign back button`.  When I navigate into my app (doesn't matter if it's 1, 2, 3, or 4 pages) and click the back button, `backbutton` doesn't make it to the console, and the app just moves to the back.

If I change the event listener to this:

```
document.addEventListener('backbutton', onBackButton, false);
```

and

```
function onBackButton() {
    console.log("backButton");
    window.history.back();
    return false;
};
```

then I get the same result.

My script tags are at the bottom of my body tag inside index.html and are in this order:

```
<!-- Cordova reference, this is added to your app when it's built. -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script> // Empty file

<script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jqueryHelpers.js"></script>
```

Is there something blaringly obvious that I'm doing wrong here?

`platformOverrides.js` is provided by the Visual Studio template and is empty.  `index.js` is provided by the template, and is where the code posted above lives.  `jqueryHelpers.js` is just two constants, like this:

```
var APIROOT = "http://WEBAPI-ADDRESS.COM/";
var PCFGUID = "00000000-0000-0000-000E-000000000000"; // changed to Guid.Empty here for security reasons.
```

**EDIT**

I've noticed that Visual Studio is pulling down the incorrect version of Cordova also.  I'm not sure how to correct this, and I'm not sure if this is my problem or not.  I've opened a [new question for it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31396117/403404), but wanted to mention it here in case it was relevant.  I'm specifying 5.0.0, but when I look at the dynamic content while debugging, it looks like it's using 3.9.0-dev

**EDIT**

Upon further research, it looks like the version number might be correct.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31430780/403404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem and I found another question here in Stackoverflow with the answer. You can check it here [Phonegap +jquery mobile + windows phone: Back button issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15578496/phonegap-jquery-mobile-windows-phone-back-button-issue)

As a quick view here is the code that solves the problem:

```
WinJS.Application.addEventListener("backclick", function (evt) {
if (!jQuery(".ui-page-active").attr("id") == "page-home")) {
    history.back();
    // Prevent the default behavior by returning true. evt.preventDefault doesn't cancel the external code.
    return true;
}
// Execute the default behavior.
return false;
};
```

PS: I changed the code a bit to avoid the deprecated jQuery.mobile.activePage from the original answer.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try to use 'on' jQuery function. The problem is probably about the browser compability with your code. You should check the browser version on Windows Mobile. Please, read [this attachEvent article.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343%28VS.85%29.aspx)

```
function deviceReady() {

$("#backbutton").on("click",function(){
        console.log("backbutton");
         window.history.back();
         return false;
    });

}
```

And if you need this is for exit and terminating the application: [Cordova.js

```
navigator.app.exitApp();
```

Comment: Using `on` doesn't work either.  I tried using '#backbutton' as you suggested, however I don't have an element with id of backbutton, so I tried also just 'backbutton', but neither selector worked.  Same result as in my OP.

Comment: Do you think you need platformOverrides.js? Try to remove it. Maybe that library and JQMobile have conflict?

Comment: Sorry, I realized that you told it is empty. Well. Check for jQueryHelpers? Our code is so simple. It works on my project. I have already used it. There should be something wrong differently. Is there any warning or error on Web Console?

Comment: jQueryHelpers actually just has to constants in it, no code per se.  I'll update my post with the code.  There are no compiler warnings or errors.  I don't have access to Web Console, this is a mobile application so I'm using the WP emulator.

Comment: I use WebStorm IDE and can see all things on web first. If it works on web it wont be problem on mobile also.

Comment: I will also note, that when I use the Ripple emulator (chrome) to emulate android, the backbutton event doesn't fire either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83131/discussion-between-deniz-and-johnie-karr).

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside deviceReady or mobileinit:

```
   $(document).bind('keydown', function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode == 27) {
        // Prevent default (disable the back button behavior)
        event.preventDefault();

        $.mobile.back();
      }
    });
```

I hope helps!

Comment: I tried a couple variations of this and it was the same result as described in my OP.

Answer (score 0):

Even I am facing same issue when I upgrade cordova from 3.6.6 to 5.1.1 version. After upgrading cordova backbutton not triggering. Finally I did below the changes in `cordova.js` after that it working fine:

```
//var APP_PLUGIN_NAME = Number(cordova.platformVersion.split('.')[0]) >= 4 ? 'CoreAndroid' : 'App';
var APP_PLUGIN_NAME = 'App';
```