# Visual Studio 2015 Using Incorrect Cordova Version

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm new to Cordova development, and I'm using Visual Studio 2015 RC on Windows 10.  I'm targeting Cordova 5.0.0, however, when I'm debugging using the Windows Phone emulator, and I take a look at the dynamic code, I notice that Visual Studio is pulling down Cordova 3.9.0-dev.  Am I missing something here?

[image: Configured for Cordova 5.0.0]
[image: Visual Studio is using 3.9.0-dev]

**Edit**

I'll note, that [other than this problem over here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31373711/403404), I'm not seeing any obvious issues with this, and the Cordova plugins I'm using do work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a GIT user, but, it appears that Cordova.js is different for each platform (Windows, Windows Phone, iOS, Android, etc...).  For Windows Phone 8, which I've been focusing on, it looks like the latest version is in fact 3.9.0-dev, that is assuming I'm looking in the right place.

https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf

https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-windows-phone.git;a=summary

https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-wp8.git;a=summary